# How to open a .DWG file in Autocad 2014 through C#

Tags: c#, winforms, autocad

Hi I have a requirement in which I have to open a drawing file stored in C:\Temp Folder.
I tried the following code

```
public void launchacad(string pth)  //pth is the path to the .DWG file
        {
            const string progID = "AutoCAD.Application.19.1";                

            const string exePath = @"C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2014\acad.exe";

            AcadApplication acApp = null;

            try
            {
                acApp =
                  (AcadApplication)Marshal.GetActiveObject(progID);
            }
            catch { }

            if (acApp != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An instance of AutoCAD is already running.");
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {                            
                    ProcessStartInfo psi =new ProcessStartInfo(exePath);
                    psi.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Temp";
                    psi.Arguments = pth;
                    Process pr = Process.Start(psi);

                    pr.WaitForInputIdle();                            

                    while (acApp == null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            acApp =(AcadApplication)Marshal.GetActiveObject(progID);                            
                        }
                        catch
                        {                                    
                            Application.DoEvents();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(
                      "Cannot create or attach to AutoCAD object: "
                      + ex.Message
                    );
                }
            }

            if (acApp != null)
            {
                acApp.Visible = true;
                acApp.ActiveDocument.SendCommand("_MYCOMMAND ");
            }
        }
```

But as soon as Autocad starts it popups an error message saying `Cannot find the specified drawing.` When I use CMD.exe and type

```
"C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2014\acad.exe" "C:\Temp\41 Stabd.dwg"  It opens Autocad with the file(41 Stand.dwg) open.
```

I can't understand where I am making an error. Can someone help me out.

Comment: If AutoCAD is the program associated with ".dwg" files, have you tried just opening the file? `Process.Start(@"C:\Temp\41 Stabd.dwg");`

Comment: @GrantWinney Oh yes it is opening with this command. But if the file is associated with some other application like Trueview or something else then??

Comment: @GrantWinney pth="C:\Temp\41 Stand.dwg"

Comment: @GrantWinney naah its Stand.dwg. Its a typo.

Comment: @GrantWinney Anyways thanks a lot. atleast it started opening the DWG. Thanks

Comment: The file name contains an embedded space.  That requires you to put double-quotes around the filename so that AutoCAD doesn't think you are trying to start it with *two* command line arguments.  If you use Process.Start(pth) then this won't go wrong, Windows itself ensures that the argument is properly quoted.

Comment: I'd avoid process start altogether, and just use Activator.CreateInstance if one isn't already running.  Once AutoCAD is up, open a drawing by sending a command via ActiveDocument.SendCommand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If still the drawing persists with problems, continue on to the next set of steps.

These can be done in any order, but have been listed in the order that Autodesk recommends makes the most sense. The file can be checked after each step. If things appear back to normal, there is no need to continue on to the rest of the steps.
​Open a blank DWG and type RECOVER at the command line. Browse to the problematic file to - allow AutoCAD a chance to restore the file.

- Type OVERKILL at the command line, and select all objects. Check or uncheck properties to include or ignore, then click OK.
- Type DELCON at the command line, and select all objects.
- Type BREP and select all objects (if there are solids or surfaces in the file)
- Type -SCALELISTEDIT, then "R" for reset, then "Y" for yes.
- Type FILTERS, then click on the 'delete filters' button.
- The DGNPURGE tool can be run if the file size is unexpectedly very large:  http://knowledge.autodesk.com/article/AutoCAD-DWG-files-unexpectedly-increase-in-file-size
- Try using a different version of AutoCAD to open the drawing, such as AutoCAD 2013 vs. AutoCAD 2015 or plain AutoCAD vs. AutoCAD Architecture, etc. Try different computers if available.
- Open a blank DWG, and try to attach the problematic file as an XREF. If it allows you to attach the file, try next to BIND it to the current file. If that works, run the repair steps listed above.
- Use the SAVEAS command to save the DWG in an older file format. Attempt to open the newly created file.
- Export the file to DXF format using the DXFOUT command. Next, open a blan DWG and use the DXFIN command to import the file just created.

< Restore the Layout tabs:

1. Right-Click one of the default layout tabs
2. Select 'From Template...'
3. Open the original file
4. Choose the layout tabs to restore. (It is recommended to do this one tab at a time, in case one or more layout tabs are corrupted)

> Move drawing objects between model and paper space. You may find that only one drawing space is usable in your file, although your main concern is model space:
>   ​​1. Create a new layout and if need be, create a viewport.
>
> Use CHSPACE to move all the geometry to paper space.
>
> Create a new drawing and use the Design Center (ADC) to move the layout from the damaged file into it.
>
> Use CHSPACE again to move the geometry back to model space.
>
> Restore the original layouts from the bad file using the Design Center.
>
> Dissect the drawing. In a copy of the file, conduct a process of elimination using QSELECT to select different object types and then delete them to see if that fixes what is wrong in the file. Do PURGE All after each deletion. Eventually you should remove the problem elements and then you can choose to leave them out, copy them in again from another file, recreate them, or further troubleshoot individual items to pinpoint exactly which one is problematic. A quick start to this whole process is to delete everything in the drawing and then test it. This will quickly tell you if the issue is with a drawing object or if it is a part of the drawing database.​